# ldap authentication in active directory child domain

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

in my asp net mvc project I use ldap for authentication and authorization.

I have a subdomain named op.sep.net,that is a child of sep.net.
all users that need to be authenticated are defined in root domain sep.net, but the groups are defined in sub domain

this is my connection string in web.config file:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
  <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
  connectionStringName="ADService"
  attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
  connectionUsername="sep\at.rahimi"
  connectionPassword="1qaz!QAZ"
  connectionProtection="None" enablePasswordReset="false"
  enableSearchMethods="true" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and the connection string part:

```
 <connectionStrings>

<add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://OP-DC.op.sep.net/dc=op-dc,dc=op,dc=sep,dc=net" />
```

as I mentioned the user at.rahimi is in sep domain

my problem is that if I use LDAP://OP-DC.op.sep.net as server I,ll get "The user name or password is incorrect" and can not authenticate, but if I use LDAP://sep.net I can authenticate but I cant see those roles that are in sub domain by  `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser("at.rahimi")`
and I just can see roles in sep.net

I'll be so thank full if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting LDAP with C#, you can use the Directory Entry class to process authentication from the lower level to the root domain.
If you specify the PATH path as Schema, you can import an account from the subdomain to the root domain, or you can override the BASEDN information you are viewing by importing the PATH path and using PATH. PARENT.